# Filpping bits in binary number

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Can anyone provide a clear logic for the below problem. I am stuck with confusion.

An n bit number is given as input and OP(j) and OP(k) are applied on it one after the other. Objective is to specify how many bits will remain the same after applying these two operations.

OP(i) implies flipping of *each ith* bit. i > 0

Comment: It sounds very much as though, by definition, *n - 2* bits remain the same, except if *j == k*, in which case no bits change. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: i am actually confused by the definition of OP(i).. Sorry i have edited the same. It says flipping of each ith bit.

Comment: Well, that made the question more meaningful, at least. :) What is it that confuses you, though? And also, why is the question tagged "c"?

Comment: If one bit gets flipped twice, does it count as a changed bit compared to the original?

Comment: What does it mean by flipping each ith bit. As per my understanding if i indicates a position then only that bit will be flipped.. but each? .. help please

Comment: As I understand it, if you do OP(2) then every second bit gets flipped, OP(3) flips every third bit. If you are unsure, and this is a school assignment, then you need to ask your teacher of teachers assistant.

Comment: +Joachim Pileborg - then  what does OP(1) means

Comment: Every bit? Really, ask your teacher or the one who gave you the assignment. All I'm doing is guessing, your teacher is the only one who knows for certain and can help you.

Comment: Sorry to bother but i got this question in some coding contest. all i did was n-2 thing. But i am interested if there is some other logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the operation OP(i) will change every 'i'th bit, so it changes a total of floor(n / i) bits. Chaining the operation makes things tricky. If the same parameter is passed in twice, then the same values will be flipped, the overall number of flipped bits is 0 since we revert to the original value.

If the second operation uses a different value (j), then you need to add floor(n / j) and then subtract 2*M, where M is the number of common multiples of i and j within the n range.  This is because you'll be flipping any common multiples twice and reverting them back to their original value, but having accumulated them twice (once in OP(i) and once in OP(j)), you need to subtract 2 from the total to account for it.

Answer (score 0):

For k != j, n-2 bits remains same.
When k == j, n-1 bits remains same.