# Flipping a bit and to tell the number of bits remain same after flipping

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am confused by the below question.
Flipping a bit means changing the bit from 0 to 1 and vice versa.An operation OP(i) would result in flipping of binary digit as follows.
Performing OP(i) would result in flipping of each ith bit from starting i>0

An n bit number is given as input and OP(j) and OP(k) are applied on it one after the other. Objective is to specify how many bits will remain the same after applying these two operations.

When I have applied the logic floor(n/i)+floor(n/j)-2 it doesn't give me the expected solution.
example:
binary number:10110101101
            i:3
            j:4
expected output:6
But I got 3.Please tell me how to approach this problem.
I have also checked this solution [Filpping bits in binary number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514429/filpping-bits-in-binary-number/33514714#33514714) .But they have also mentioned the same logic.

Comment: May be we need not use floor function here.
If there are n bits from bit 0 to bit n-1,
If nothing is done, all n bits remain unchanged
If Op(i) is done, n - i -1 bits unchanged.
If Op(j) is done, n - j -1 bits unchanged.
Therefore, if Op(i), and Op(j) is done,
if i > j, (n - (i -j)) bits unchanged
else (n - (j - i)) bits unchanged.

Comment: @balabhi can you explain this with the given example in answer. 10110101101 i:3 j:4 expected output:6

Comment: @Amitabh, I am trying to understand, as to how the expected answer is 6. May be I am missing something here.

Comment: @balabhi can u explain your logic for the above given sample example.

Comment: Hi guys, My apologies. I misunderstood the problem. My original comment is wrong.

Comment: yes @balabhi I tried with your logic, but output is never coming 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the register comprises of N bits, bits 1 to N.
(1) OP(i) implies every ith bit is flipped. That is bits at i, 2*i, 3*i ...
    are flipped. Total bits flipped = floor(N/i)
(2) OP(j) implies every ith bit is flipped. That is bits at j, 2*j, 3*j ...
    are flipped. Total bits flipped = floor(N/j)
(3) Let L = LCM(i,j). Therefore, bits at L, 2*L, 3*L, ... will be
    flipped twice, implies bits unchanged are floor(N/L)

So, after OP(i) and OP(j), the total bits changed will be
floor(N/i) + floor(N/j) - 2*floor(N/L)
Number of bits unchanged = N - floor(N/i) - floor(N/j) + 2*floor(N/L)

For N=11, i=4, j=3, L = LCM(3,4) = 12,
Number of unchanged bits = 11 - 11/4 - 11/3 + 11/12 = 11 - 2 - 3 + 0 = 6

Comment: @balabhi.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int nochange_bits(String input1,int i1,int i2)
    {
        try{
        int len=input1.length();
        if(i1<1 || i2<1){
            return -1;
        }else if(i1>len && i2>len){
            return len;
        }else if(i1==i2){
            return len;
        }else{
            return (int)(len-Math.floor(len/i1)-Math.floor(len/i2)+2*Math.floor(len/(Math.abs(i1*i2) / GCF(i1, i2))));
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static int GCF(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    else return (GCF (b, a % b));
}
```

a) First, we check for all the conditions and invalidity of inputs
b) Then we calculate the LCM to get the output

Explanation: It's similar to the flipping switches problem, 
first turn we switch the i1 bits
second turn we switch the i2 bits

in the process, the bits which have the LCM(i1,i2) are turned back.

so we add the lcm back to the total